# How do I associate an application with all mime types it supports?

Tags: fedora, mime-types, file-associations

Let's say I have `xarchiver` installed by default, and associated by default with most archive types.

I've installed `engrampa`, and now want to assciate it with the various archive types instead. I don't want to change each MIME association individually.

When I uninstalled `xarchiver`, the associations for various archive types automatically changed to `engrampa`.

Is there a way to do this without uninstalling `xarchiver`? Something like "assciate application X with all MIME types it supports"?

---

I'm using Fedora 38 XFCE spin, if it matters.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/720754/xfce-set-up-global-file-associations

Comment: @MichaelD. With what flags should I run `mimeopen`?

Comment: You can query a file with `xdg-mime` and change it either systemwide `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` or per user `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` (see link).  However, there should be a xfce system dialog setting to change it as well. See "Others - MIME Type Editor" near end of this page https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/preferred-apps

Comment: @MichaelD. Note the *"I don't want to change each MIME association individually."* part of the question. I know how to change the association for an individual MIME type. I'm asking how to do it for all types an application supports at once. I believe it's possible, since uninstalling `xarchiver` automatically associated numerous archive types with the remaining archiver `engrampa`.

Answer (score 1):

To set default application use this command (untested) (copy & paste in console):

```
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/epub+zip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-7z-compressed; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-7z-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-ace; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-alz; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-arc; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-arj; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-brotli; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-brotli-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-bzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-bzip2; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/bzip2; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-bzip-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-bzip1; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-cabinet; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-cbr; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-cbz; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-cd-image; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-compress; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-cpio; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/vnd.debian.binary-package; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-ear; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-ms-dos-executable; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-gtar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-gzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/gzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-gzpostscript; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-java-archive; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lha; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzh-compressed; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lrzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzip-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzma; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzma-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzop; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-lzop-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-ms-wim; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-rar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-rar-compressed; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-rpm; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-source-rpm; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-rzip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-tarz; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-stuffit; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-war; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-xz; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-xz-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-zip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-zip-compressed; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-zoo; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/zstd; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-zstd; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-zstd-compressed-tar; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/zip; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/x-archive; \ 
xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed
```

Output of:

```
cat engrampa.desktop | grep "MimeType" | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr ";" "\n" | xargs -n1 printf "xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop %s; \\ \n"
```

---

the file `engrampa.desktop` should could be located at

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

and looks like this

https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/blob/master/data/engrampa.desktop.in.in

If you don't find it use the `find` command

Comment: The xarchiver vs engrampa situation was used only as an example, and hardcoding the list of archive formats in this answer is probably not the best idea. It should be possible to `grep` the desktop file for a list of supported MIMEs to automate this. And it's a little sad that there's no built-in tool for this. :(

Comment: I did "grep" the desktop file and generated this list - `cat engrampa.desktop | grep "MimeType" | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr ";" "\n" | xargs -n1 printf "xdg-mime default engrampa.desktop %s; \\ \n"`